# IE 11 browser displaying 'You're not connected to a network' page while trying to access an App Cached offline page

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, html5-appcache, offline-caching, offlineapps

**Background:**

I have built a web page that should work even offline. This page is made by following **'AppCache'** guidelines.

My web browser is an IE11 on a HP windows 8 tablet.

When I hit the direct URL of the page on the physical server(Oracle weblogic) then I am able to access the page. The same page is accessible via the IE11 browser even when I turn off the network connections.

**Issue:**

When I access the same page via the corporate gateway(F5 & OHS) then the page is available when there is network connectivity.  But once I turnoff the network connectivity then I see the page '***You're not connected to a network***'.

When I connect back to the network and try accessing the same page then I can see the resources requested by my page are all served from the local cache browser ( I inspect the network via IE developer tools).

**Am not sure what is happening. I would like to access my page even when there is no connectivity.**

Note:

My pages are accessible via the gateway using only 'HTTPS'. Where as my direct access to the server is using 'HTTP'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like IE keeps its offline content in different security zones. And these zones vary depending on connected to the network or offline.

It seems when I was connected to the network then the 'Local Intranet' security zone was applied. But when I go offline the 'Internet' security zone was applied by the IE browser.

**My web page started working fine when I added the site domain name to the IE -> Internet Options -> Security -> Trusted Sites.**

Since then the same security zone was applied when am connected to the network or offline.